# How to split a word in the given positive or negative fraction

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

So for example I have a word: swimming and running.
Swimming consist of 8 letters and running of seven, if there is a given fraction, like 3/4 for swimming and -2/7 for running. It would need to give me swimmi and
ng because the fraction given to running is negative so it needs to start at the end.

I know it is with this command

```
echo ${word:0:${#word}*$frac}
```

And I get

```
swimmi
ru
```

But this doesn't work for a negative number
and I expected this

```
swimmi
ng
```

Comment: How about `echo "word/fraction" | awk -F "/" '{print $1 " " $2}'`

Comment: Please, post a proper sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the distinction of negative or positive fraction.

```
word="running"
frac=-2/7

if [[ $frac =~ ^- ]]; then
  # negative
  echo "${word:${#word}*$frac}"
else
  # positive
  echo "${word:0:${#word}*$frac}"
fi
```

Output:

```
ng
```